# Prolong UIPickerView [selectRow: inComponent: animated:]'s animation

Tags: ios, animation, uipickerview

I'm using a `UIPickerView` to display random numbers. The user can press a button, and thus trigger a random selection of a number inside the `UIPickerView`.

It does not matter how many objects or numbers are being displayed inside the `UIPickerView`, when I call the method:

```
[self.picker selectRow:randomRow inComponent:0 animated:YES];
```

It always gets animated with the same time interval.

Is there any option or method to prolong the animation time interval of above method?

I have tried placing it in an animation block:

```
[UIView beginAnimations:@"identifier" context:nil];
// code
[UIView commitAnimations];
```

but this seems to be a dead end.

I have also tried executing it in a completion blocks:

```
// 0.34f is the approximate defualt apple animation
[UIView animateWithDuration:0.34f animations:^{

[self.picker selectRow:randomRow inComponent:0 animated:YES];

} completion:^(BOOL finished) {

[UIView animateWithDuration:0.34f animations:^{

    [self.picker selectRow:randomRow inComponent:0 animated:YES];

} completion:nil];
}];
```

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: This might help -https://github.com/fidgetware/CCPickerView?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I made a project and play for a while till I find out this tricky solution. It base on the method `performSelector:afterDelay`

Here is the touch up inside code of your button:

```
- (void)click:(id)sender
{
    int randomRow = <>;//Your random method

    int currentRow = [_picker selectedRowInComponent:0];

    int i = 0;
    while(1)
    {
        i++;
        NSString *rowToSelectString = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d", currentRow];
        NSDictionary *rowToSelectDictionary = @{@"row":rowToSelectString};

        if(randomRow < currentRow)
        {
            // Go backward
            currentRow--;
        }
        else
        {
            // Go forward
            currentRow++;
        }


        [self performSelector:@selector(selectRowInPicker:) withObject:rowToSelectDictionary afterDelay:i*0.1];//Change the delay as you want

        if(currentRow == randomRow)
        {
            break;
        }
    }
}
```

And the trick:

```
-(void)selectRowInPicker:(NSDictionary *)rowToSelectDictionary
{
    NSInteger row = [[rowToSelectDictionary objectForKey:@"row"] integerValue];
    [_picker selectRow:row inComponent:0 animated:YES];
}
```

This work well for me. Tell me if you're having problem with it.

Comment: Thanks! it's not exactly what i need, but it does point me in the right direction!

Answer (score 5):

Finally, I have implemented a "thinner" version of the chosen answer:

```
- (IBAction)spinTheWheelButtonPressed:(UIButton *)sender
{
    for (int i = 0; i < 30; i++) {

        NSUInteger randomRow = arc4random_uniform((int)[self.dataSource count]);

        [self performSelector:@selector(selectRowInPicker:) withObject:@(randomRow) afterDelay:i*0.1];
    }
}

- (void)selectRowInPicker:(NSNumber *)randomRow
{
    [self.picker selectRow:[randomRow integerValue] inComponent:0 animated:YES];
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I had a similar problem , but unfortunately there is no easy way to delay the animation thats as far as I know.
So I went around and placed a UIView on top of the pickerView. I subclassed that view to pass all of its touches to the pickerView and when something was selected I just drew a layer with less opacity in the view where the row would usually come to rest and animated it in a animation block since the selection is always right at the middle of the pickerView.